# Mongo DB is not updating document with $set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document in the DB

```
{
    "_id" : "jpC6fH4xNSY8DFsHd",
    "result" : [
        {
            "form": 2,
            "term" : 1,
            "Mathematics" : {

                "exam" : 15,
                "project" : 22

            },
            "Physics" : {
                "exam" : 15,
                "project" : 22
            },
            "Chemistry" : {
                "exam" : 15,
                "project" : 22
            }
        },
        {
            "form": 3,
            "term" : 1,
            "Mathematics" : {

                "exam" : 15,
                "project" : 22

            },
            "Physics" : {
                "exam" : 15,
                "project": 22
            },
           //I want to add chemistry here!
        },

    ]
}
```

I want to update "Chemistry" object in the document where `result.form: 3` and `result.term: 1` but wouldn't update. I noticed that it's updating `"result.form": 2` and `"result.term": 1`

```
db.results.update({_id:'jpC6fH4xNSY8DFsHd','result.term':1,'result.form':3},{$set:{'result.$.Chemistry':{exam:12,position:33}}})
```

I'm using MongoDB shell version: 3.2.15 on Linux Mint 18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match the multiple fields inside an array and

2) To update the fields inside the object you have to use `.dot` notation

```
db.results.update(
  { "_id": "jpC6fH4xNSY8DFsHd",
    "result": { "$elemMatch": { "term": 1, "form": 3 }}
  },
  { "$set": {
    "result.$.Chemistry.exam": 12,
    "result.$.Chemistry.position": 33
  }}
)
```

Comment: Anthony Winzlet, you're a lifesaver. Worked perfectly!